# Fastest way to conditionally strip off the right part of a string

Tags: string, vb.net, split

I need to remove the numeric part at the end of a string. Here are some examples:

- `"abcd1234"` -> `"abcd"`
- `"a3bc45"` -> `"a3bc"`
- `"kj3ih5"` -> `"kj3ih"`

You get the idea.

I implemented a function which works well for this purpose.

```
Function VarStamm(name As String) As String
    Dim i, a As Integer
    a = 0
    For i = Len(name) To 1 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Mid(name, i, 1)) = False Then
            i = i + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If i <= Len(name) Then
        VarStamm = name.Substring(0, i - 1)
    Else
        VarStamm = name
    End If
End Function
```

The question is: is there any ***faster*** (more efficient in speed) way to do this? The problem is, I call this function within a loop with 3 million iterations and it would be nice to have it be more efficient.

I know about the `String.LastIndexOf` method, but I don't know how to use it when I need the index of the last connected number within a string.

Comment: The function returns only the left part, but that is ok for my purpose

Comment: That looks like it'd be pretty efficient to me.  You might be able to create your own method which is more efficient than `IsNumeric`.  It's probably faster to get the current character via array syntax (i.e. `name(i)`), too.  But other than those small things, the general algorithm looks good.  My biggest complaint would be your use of legacy VB6 style functions like `Mid`, `IsNumeric`, and `Len`, rather than the newer .NET equivalents, but I don't know that the .NET equivalents would really be any faster.

Comment: Looks good, unless you need to handle the case where your string would end with something else than a number (and you still need to split it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was skeptical that the `Array.FindLastIndex` method was actually faster, so I tested it myself.  I borrowed the testing code posted by Amessihel, but added a third method:

```
Function VarStamm3(name As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = name.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Not Char.IsDigit(name(i)) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    Return name.Substring(0, i + 1)
End Function
```

It uses your original algorithm, but just swaps out the old VB6-style string methods for newer .NET equivalent ones.  Here's the results on my machine:

```
RunTime :
 - VarStamm : 00:00:07.92
 - VarStamm2 : 00:00:00.60
 - VarStamm3 : 00:00:00.23
```

As you can see, your original algorithm was already quite well tuned.  The problem wasn't the loop.  The problem was `Mid`, `IsNumeric`, and `Len`.  Since Tim's method didn't use those, it was much faster.  But, if you stick with a manual for loop, it's twice as fast as using `Array.FindLastIndex`, all things being equal

Comment: Yes indeed, it's worth mentioning that the issue is not related to the algorithm. Sounds like your implementation took the first place.

Comment: @SteveDoggart did you remove the `Dim part2 = text.Substring(lastNonDigitIndex)` from Tim's solution when timing? I am not a fan of long one-liners and am interested in the speed difference if any.

Comment: @Mary good question. I just copied the code from Amessihel’s answer and added the new method to it.

Comment: It looks like, in the VarStamm2 method, he had removed that unnecessary line, so that’s what I tested with.

Comment: Thank you, Steve.

Comment: Thanks to everyone helping me with this! Seems like your function is the fastest for my application!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.FindLastIndex` and then `Substring`:

```
Dim lastNonDigitIndex = Array.FindLastIndex(text.ToCharArray(), Function(c) Not char.IsDigit(c))

If lastNonDigitIndex >= 0
    lastNonDigitIndex += 1
    Dim part1 = text.Substring(0, lastNonDigitIndex)
    Dim part2 = text.Substring(lastNonDigitIndex)
End If
```

Comment: @Amessihel: slower than what and why?

Comment: @Amessihel: you tested both or why you say it's slower? The slowest part of it is `text.ToCharArray`

Comment: My bad, your code is WAY faster. I'll publish an answer to prove it.

Comment: @Amessihel: if you wanted an even faster version you needed to create an extension method for `String.FindLastIndex` that takes a `predicate As Func(Of Char, Boolean)`. Then you can loop the string backwards without using `ToCharArray` which always creates a new `Char()`. The body of this method was: `For i As Int32 = text.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
   If predicate(text(i)) Then Return i
  Next
  Return -1`

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you! Great success :)

Answer (score 2):

Given your function `VarStamm` and Tim Schmelter's one named `VarStamm2`, here is a small test performance I wrote. I typed an arbitrary long String with a huge right part, and ran the functions one million times.

```
Module StackOverlow

    Sub Main()
        Dim testStr = "azekzoerjezoriezltjreoitueriou7657678678797897898997897978897898797989797"

        Console.WriteLine("RunTime :" + vbNewLine +
               " - VarStamm : " + getTimeSpent(AddressOf VarStamm, testStr) + vbNewLine +
               " - VarStamm2 : " + getTimeSpent(AddressOf VarStamm2, testStr))

    End Sub

    Function getTimeSpent(f As Action(Of String), str As String) As String
        Dim sw As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch()
        Dim ts As TimeSpan

        sw.Start()
        For i = 1 To 1000000
            f(str)
        Next
        sw.Stop()
        ts = sw.Elapsed
        Return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10)
    End Function

    Function VarStamm(name As String) As String
        Dim i, a As Integer
        a = 0
        For i = Len(name) To 1 Step -1
            If IsNumeric(Mid(name, i, 1)) = False Then
                i = i + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If i <= Len(name) Then
            VarStamm = name.Substring(0, i - 1)
        Else
            VarStamm = name
        End If
    End Function

    Function VarStamm2(name As String) As String
        Dim lastNonDigitIndex = Array.FindLastIndex(name.ToCharArray(), Function(c) Not Char.IsDigit(c))

        If lastNonDigitIndex >= 0 Then
            lastNonDigitIndex += 1
            Return name.Substring(0, lastNonDigitIndex)
        End If
        Return name
    End Function
End Module
```

Here is the output I got:

```
RunTime :
 - VarStamm : 00:00:38.33
 - VarStamm2 : 00:00:02.72
```

So yes, you should choose his answer, his code is both pretty and efficient.

Comment: Your suspicions weren't entirely wrong.  See my answer.